# Deploy app using cordova CLI to WP8 device

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cmd, command-line-interface

I am struggling to deploy helloworld application to my Windows Phone 8.1 device using Cordova command line interface. When I build application using `cordova build --release` I can easily deploy application to the device from VS Express 2012, however when I use `cordova run wp8 --device` I get this error 
[image: deploy error]
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution. It is related to `HRESULT 0x89721800` exception from "Application Deployment" executable from Windows Phone SDK. To fix this you have to go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\` and remove all folders.